# How to make body background image transparent in css?

Tags: css

As per my knowledge there is no css property to make background image transparent,
I'm trying again and again but still I'm far from solution, 
Here is my approach:

```
body {
    background-image: url("PPI01.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    filter: opacity(opacity: 30%);
    z-index: -1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I looked for other so questions and found something like, but problem remains.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put your background to body::after

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
body {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

body::after {
  background: url(http://kingofwallpapers.com/background-image-laptop/background-image-laptop-018.jpg);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;   
}

div {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
   The text will not affected by the body
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got you buddy, thanks for your help. It looks that you have shown easiest solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach is to use an absolute position image as the background and set the image with the following property,

```
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Using image source URL inside stylesheet make it hard to change the source dynamically.

Usually, the background image is pre-processed, you also might consider making it a transparent PNG file first before upload it into your static server, so you can make the image transparent using image process application like PS, Sketch.

Answer (score 0):

I sharing you my answer, because I think it's a bit better than the accepted solution, mainly because with my solution you can set image URL in HTML, as I need. You can also easyly make different CSS class for different opacity levels :)

CSS:

```css
body.light-bg {
  background-position-x: 50% !important;
  background-position-y: 50% !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
body.light-bg::before {
  background: white;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.35;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<body style="background: url(image.png)" class="light-bg"></body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use rgba background property with white color and opacity.

```
background; rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) url(IMAGE_PATH); /* Add other attributes as required */
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `opacity` property to set the value. The allowed values are from 0 to 1.

```
body {
    background-image: url("PPI01.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: -1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Check the complete [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) on W3C.

Comment: note that the content will be affected with opacity

Comment: Agree. My bad. Just realized.