# jQuery css set background-image on body:after

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using `body:after` to set page wallpaper.

```
body:after
{
    background-image: url('assets/img/wallpapers/<?php echo $getWallpaperFile; ?>');
}
```

CSS

```
content: ' ';
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0.6;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 0;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

That code is working OK when I try to reload the page.

But now I want to change that background using jQuery.

```
$("body:after").css("background-image", "url('http://hdwallpapersrocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Colorful-new-born-feathers-awesome-wallpapers.jpg')");
```

Tried and not working.

My question, is it possible to set `background-image` to `body:after` on jQuery?

Comment: `is it possible to set background-image to body:after on jQuery?` **NO** it is not possible, the pseudo selectors does not work in Jquery.

Comment: Pseudo elements, such as `:before` and `:after` are not part of the DOM, so cannot be selected by jQuery. Why are you even using `:after` in this case anyway?

Comment: Just remove `:after`  selector

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I need to set body image with opacity except content, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312909/how-to-make-body-background-image-transparent-in-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery can't target `:before` and `:after`.

What you could do is this instead:

```
$('body').addClass('loaded');
```

Then in the css:

```
.body.loaded:after {
  /*background image*/
}
```

---

Since you've mentioned in comments that it's coming from javascript, instead of having an `:after`

You could just have a div replace the after with a class name.

Then you can just target `$('body .newDiv');` and it will work.

Comment: Hi... how about if the image get from string on jQuery?

Comment: Then you'll have to change your html structure so it isn't targeting a `:after` as jQuery won't be able to change it. @HiDayurieDave

Comment: Please let me know the example :)

Comment: Updated. Instead of using `:after` you basically create a new element with a class name instead and use that instead of `:after` to do the same job. @HiDayurieDave